# Visual Studio Installer not overwriting files in target application directory

Tags: visual-studio, dll, installation, copy

I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution that contains several projects.
Most projects in this solution write a .dll when built.
My installer project in this solution copies these .dlls to a target application directory.

My uninstaller for this solution does not remove these .dlls, even though it should.

My installer doesn't overwrite old versions of existing .dlls, which causes my application not to function.

If I delete the existing .dlls prior to install, the application works well.

I've monkeyed with many many settings in the solution for these .dlls.  Nothing seems to work.

I've added extra copy actions to the install project, in an attempt to overwrite existing .dlls.  A couple of these extra copy actions can not be deleted, because the delete choice is disabled from the drop-down list when I right-click on them.  Weirdly, the original detected dependencies can be deleted.

Any ideas are most welcome.
Thanks,
-Vince

Comment: Maybe a stupid question: you're sure the program that is using the DLL's is not running, correct?  You of course cannot delete a DLL when it is being used by another program.

Comment: The program using the DLLs is not running.